# How to set HTMLField's widget's height in Admin?

Tags: django, tinymce, django-tinymce

I have a HTMLField in a model as it's the laziest way to utilize tinymce widget in Admin. But the problem is that the textarea field doesn't have "rows" property set. So the textarea doesn't have enough height comfortable enough for editing in Admin. Is there any way to set the height of HTMLField without defining a ModelAdmin class?

**Update:**

I solved the problem by using the following code:

```
def create_mce_formfield(db_field):
    return db_field.formfield(widget = TinyMCE(
        attrs = {'cols': 80, 'rows': 30},
        mce_attrs = {
            'external_link_list_url': reverse('tinymce.views.flatpages_link_list'),
            'plugin_preview_pageurl': reverse('tinymce-preview', args= ('tinymce',)),
            'plugins': "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
            'theme_advanced_buttons1': "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            'theme_advanced_buttons2': "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            'theme_advanced_buttons3': "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            'theme_advanced_buttons4': "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
            'theme_advanced_toolbar_location': "top",
            'theme_advanced_toolbar_align': "left",
            'theme_advanced_statusbar_location': "bottom",
            'theme_advanced_resizing': True,
            'extended_valid_elements': "iframe[src|title|width|height|allowfullscreen|frameborder|webkitAllowFullScreen|mozallowfullscreen|allowFullScreen]",
        },
    ))

class TinyMCEFlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'content': return create_mce_formfield(db_field)
        return super(TinyMCEFlatPageAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

in settings.py

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,xhtmlxtras,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
    "theme_advanced_buttons3_add" : "cite,abbr",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
}
```

all options :

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:Advanced_theme

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Buttons/controls

Answer (score 1):

I personally think it is easier just to set a [media definition on the admin class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions) to get TinyMCE activated on an admin form.

However, to answer your question, you probably want to tweak the widget the form uses to display that field. See the [customizing widget instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances) in the documentation for this. You could pass a row attribute to the widget to make it larger.